# Declaring Unknown Number of User Inputted Variables?

Tags: c

I am a new programmer looking to learn about loops and interacting with a user.

I am trying to write a few programs with C that involve a user inputting a range of numbers, and then scanning those variables and doing a few things with them. However, I know that you're supposed to declare your variables at the beginning of the program. The problem is, I don't know how to declare an unknown number of variables at the beginning of the program without explicitly declaring the max number of variables could possibly be included. Does anyone have any advice about how to loop scanf() for an unknown number of variables?

Including below is a limited version of code, so everyone knows what I'm trying to do.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main() {
double Num;
double a,b,c;
double max,min;
int i=0;

    printf("How many numbers? > ");
    scanf("%lf", &Num);

    printf("OK, now please enter ");
    printf("%lf", Num);
    printf(" floating point numbers > ");

    while(i<=Num) {
    scanf("%lf", &a);
    scanf("%lf", &b);
    }
```

Comment: Sidenote: you **do realize** that format strings are great because you can, er... use them as **format strings?** `printf("OK, now please enter %lf floating point numbers > ", Num);` and `scanf("%lf %lf", &a, &b);`... Also, your loop never ends since you don't increment `i`. Furthermore, you should 1. be checking the return value of `scanf()` and 2. not be using `scanf()` at all and use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: Ah, so if you include the variable at the end of the command line, you don't have to include another printf() line? Thank you very much!

Comment: that's **the** purpose of format strings... >.<

Comment: Also, it would be best to enter the number of numbers as an integer, not as a floating point value; it might be even better to just read numbers until you get EOF or a conversion failure.  You should check the return value from `scanf()` so you know it worked.  You can read pairs of numbers with `if (scanf("%lf %lf", &a, &b) != 2) { ...handle EOF or error... }`.

Comment: One way of handling an indefinite number of values is to store them in an array.  You can use a fixed size array, or a VLA (variable length array) if you can use C99, or a dynamically allocated array (using `malloc()` and `realloc()`).  In each case, you need to make sure you don't try to store more values than will fit in the array lest you run into a 'buffer overflow'.  Alternatively, you can read values into the same variable over and over, processing each value as you go (count it, determine minimum or maximum, accumulate for mean or geometric mean, etc).  This is best if it is an option.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use a pointer to an array of doubles to hold your numbers and allocate the memory for it at runtime...

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main() 
    {
        double Num;
        double *a,*b,*c;
        double max,min;
        int i=0;

        printf("How many numbers? > ");
        scanf("%lf", &Num);

        a = malloc( sizeof( double ) * Num );
        b = malloc( sizeof( double ) * Num );
        c = malloc( sizeof( double ) * Num );

        if( !a || !b || !c )
        {
            printf( "Out of memory\n" );
            exit( -1 );
        }

        printf("OK, now please enter %lf floating point numbers > ", Num);

        while(i<=Num) 
        {
            scanf("%lf", &a[i]);
            scanf("%lf", &b[i]);
        }

        // do stuff with c

        free( a );
        free( b );
        free( c );

        exit( 0 );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to have all the variables available in memory in the same time?

If you plan for example to compute the maximum of an unspecified number of user input numbers, you just need two variables, not an unspecified number of variables.

Comment: This is arguably a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Yes. I'm also trying to calculate the geometric mean although this could actually be calculated by just creating another variable and summing this as the loop continues.

I think.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I also argued with myself whether to put this as a comment, but I noticed the `max` and `min` identifiers in his program so I thought this was actually an answer to his problem.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion (with minimal changes):

```
   #include <stdio.h>

   int main() {
     int Num;
     double a,b,c;
     double max,min;
     int i=0;

     printf("How many numbers? > ");
     scanf("%d", &Num);

     printf("OK, now please enter %d floating point numbers >", Num);
     for (i=0; i < Num; i++) {
       scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &a, &b, &c);
       printf ("you entered: a=%lf, b=%lf, c=%lf\n", a, b, c);

     }

     return 0;
    }
```

NOTE: This code assumes you only want the current a,b, and c (for example, to compare it them with your current min and max).  If you want to keep *all* the a, b and c values you enter ...l then you need to store them in an array or a list.

C++ has a "vector<>" class that's made-to-order.  If you use a C "array", however, you generally need to know the maximum #/elements up-front, *before* you allocate the array.  You can mitigate this somewhat by using "malloc()" - realloc() lets you change the array size at runtime.